# Indices of n largest values in lower triangular region of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance

I have a numpy cosine similarity matrix. I want to find the indices of the n largest values, but exclude the `1.0`'s on the diagonals and only for the lower triangular region in it.

```
similarities = [[ 1.          0.18898224  0.16903085]
 [ 0.18898224  1.          0.67082039]
 [ 0.16903085  0.67082039  1.        ]]
```

In this case, if I want the two highest values, I would want it to return `[1, 0]` and `[2, 1]`.

I have tried using `argpartition` but this does not return what I'm looking for

```
n_select = 1
most_similar = (-similarities).argpartition(n_select, axis=None)[:n_select]
```

How can I get the n highest values excluding the diagonal 1's and also exclude the upper triangular elements?

Comment: Aren't [1, 0] and [2, 1] the two largest values? Is the matrix always symmetric and you are interested only in the lower/upper triangular part?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I had the indices wrong. The matrix will always be symmetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One approach with `np.tril_indices` -

```
def n_largest_indices_tril(a, n=2):
    m = a.shape[0]
    r,c = np.tril_indices(m,-1)
    idx = a[r,c].argpartition(-n)[-n:]
    return zip(r[idx], c[idx])
```

Sample run -

```
In [39]: a
Out[39]: 
array([[ 1.  ,  0.4 ,  0.59,  0.15,  0.29],
       [ 0.4 ,  1.  ,  0.03,  0.57,  0.57],
       [ 0.59,  0.03,  1.  ,  0.9 ,  0.52],
       [ 0.15,  0.57,  0.9 ,  1.  ,  0.37],
       [ 0.29,  0.57,  0.52,  0.37,  1.  ]])

In [40]: n_largest_indices_tril(a, n=2)
Out[40]: [(2, 0), (3, 2)]

In [41]: n_largest_indices_tril(a, n=3)
Out[41]: [(4, 1), (2, 0), (3, 2)]
```

**Approach #2**

For performance, we might want to avoid generating all lower triangular indices and instead work with a mask, giving us a second method to solve our case, like so -

```
def n_largest_indices_tril_v2(a, n=2):
    m = a.shape[0]
    r = np.arange(m)
    mask = r[:,None] > r
    idx = a[mask].argpartition(-n)[-n:]

    clens = np.arange(m).cumsum()    
    grp_start = clens[:-1]
    grp_stop = clens[1:]-1    

    rows = np.searchsorted(grp_stop, idx)+1    
    cols  = idx - grp_start[rows-1]
    return zip(rows, cols)
```

#### Runtime test

```
In [143]: # Setup symmetric array 
     ...: N = 1000
     ...: a = np.random.rand(N,N)*0.9
     ...: np.fill_diagonal(a,1)
     ...: m = a.shape[0]
     ...: r,c = np.tril_indices(m,-1)
     ...: a[r,c] = a[c,r]

In [144]: %timeit n_largest_indices_tril(a, n=2)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.5 ms per loop

In [145]: %timeit n_largest_indices_tril_v2(a, n=2)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.85 ms per loop
```

**For `n` smallest indices**

For getting `n` smallest ones, simply use `ndarray.argpartition(n)[:n]` instead for both of the approaches.

Comment: Thanks! I can't test this at the moment, but it makes a lot of sense. Just curious, would the n *smallest* indices be `idx = a[r,c].argpartition(-n)[:-n]`

Comment: @Adam_G `a[r,c].argpartition(n)[:n]` rather.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the diagonal elements of a square matrix have a unique property: i+j=n, where n is matrix dimension.
Then, you can just find the n + number of (diagonal elements) max elements of the array and then iterate through them and exclude the tuples  (i,j) where i+j=n.
Hope it helps!